# Java create file odt with jOpendocument use a template

Tags: java, templates, line, break

I'm using jOpenDocument to create file odt use a template in this link http://www.jopendocument.org/start_text_2.html

But i want to make a odt file like this:

Content 1 (//multile line with line break)

Template (//with some parameter in template)

Content2 (//multile line with line break)

Templaete (//with some parameter in template)
..

..

..

I don't know how to insert line break (and page break) into file odt using jOpenDocument. And How to repeat file template. Please give me a example. I just start code java. In PHP, i'm use phpodt and it work fine! thank you!